# Iron Python System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure' from assembly 'System.Core'

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am now working with Iron Python to run python based dll in C#.

So I have this line in my C# Code:

```
public void Runpython(string name, string id)
{
   var engine = Python.CreateEngine();    
   
   //Get Dll
   var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
   var fullPath = @$"{path}\PythonService.dll";
   engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath));
   
   //Get pythonservice.py file         
   var scope = engine.Runtime.ImportModule("pythonservice");

   //Get PythonService class
   var pythonService = scope.GetVariable("PythonService");

   //Run function
   var pyService = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(pythonService);
   var result = pyService.save(name, id);
            
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

And the exception occurs in this line: `var scope = engine.Runtime.ImportModule("pythonservice");`  when it was trying to get the `pythonservice.py` file which I wrapped inside dll.

Can I know what is the issue here that's causing this?

I'm using Iron Python 2.7.11 and my C# Class Library and Console App both are .NET Core 3.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same work whitout IronPython

install your libraries in "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" or any python environment

and try this:

```
public string Run(string scriptFilePatch, string args)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"; // or any python environment

    psi.Arguments = $"\"{scriptFilePatch}\" {args}";

    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    string errors = "", result = "";

    using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    }
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result, writer);
    string decodedString = writer.ToString();

    return decodedString;
}
```

Usage:

```
 Run("c:/code/download.py", "\"imageUrl\" \"fileName}"");
```

and read the arguments in python whit this

Python Code :

```
    import sys
    url = sys.argv[1] #arg {imageUrl} recived from c# code
    fileName = sys.argv[2] #arg {fileName} recived from c# code
```

and for return data to c# code you should use this :

```
b = any_object;
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytearray(b,"utf-8"))
```

Comment: Hi, this application is needed to host on Docker later on. Does this usage able to host on Docker as well?

Comment: hi. I tested this only in windows server. I'm not sure about Docker