# Iron Python in C# Error {"type() takes no keyword arguments"}

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I have a python script that I want to call its function in .NET. The purpose was doing the string encryption in python because AWS Encryption SDK was not available in C#.

I've confirmed the python script is working and able to produce the output I want, my python version is 3.8. I've installed Iron Python 3.4 in my .NET Core 3.1 Application.

However when I try to compile the code, it gave me this exception:

```
{"type() takes no keyword arguments"}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.HandleException(InterpretedFrame frame, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`1.Call1(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller.Call0(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke0Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`1.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`9.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`1.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.Call(CodeContext context, Object func, Object arg0)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.FindAndLoadModuleFromImporter(CodeContext context, Object importer, String fullName, PythonList path, Object& ret)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.TryLoadMetaPathModule(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonList path, Object& ret)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.CompiledCode.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Infra.Aws.Encryption.AwsEncryptor.Encrypt(String encryptText) in C:\Users\app\AwsEncryption\AwsEncryptor.cs:line 44
```

Here is my C# code:

```
public string Encrypt(string encryptText)
{
    try
    {
        var searchPaths = _engine.GetSearchPaths();
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\app\AwsEncryption\Lib\site-packages");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\.nuget\packages\ironpython.stdlib\3.4.0-alpha1\contentFiles\any\any\Lib");
        _engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        
        var source = _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(
            @"C:\Users\app\AwsEncryption\encryption.py",
            Encoding.UTF8);
        var compiled = source.Compile();

        var scope = _engine.CreateScope();
        compiled.Execute(scope);

        return scope.GetVariable("encrypt")(encryptText);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The exception was throw when Iron Python tries to exeucute at this line `compiled.Execute(scope);`.

Here is my python script:

```
import base64
import aws_encryption_sdk
import boto3
from aws_encryption_sdk.identifiers import EncryptionKeyType, WrappingAlgorithm, CommitmentPolicy
from aws_encryption_sdk.key_providers.raw import RawMasterKey, WrappingKey


def get_client():
    client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(
        commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT)
    return client


def create_data_key(cmk_id, key_spec='AES_256'):
    kms_client = boto3.client('kms')
    response = kms_client.generate_data_key(KeyId=cmk_id, KeySpec=key_spec)

    return response['Plaintext']


def encrypt(source_plaintext, key_arn):
    client = get_client()

    wrapping_algorithm = WrappingAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM_IV12_TAG16_NO_PADDING

    key = create_data_key(key_arn)

    master_key = RawMasterKey(
        wrapping_key=WrappingKey(
            wrapping_algorithm=wrapping_algorithm, wrapping_key_type=EncryptionKeyType.SYMMETRIC, wrapping_key=key,
        ),
    )

    ciphertext, _encrypt_header = client.encrypt(
        source=source_plaintext, key_provider=master_key
    )

    base64_encrypted_text = [base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')]
    base64_data_key = [base64.b64encode(key).decode('utf-8')]

    return base64_encrypted_text, base64_data_key
```

Can I know what might be the issue in here?

Thank you.

Comment: if you cant find any way to solve this. 
I recommend this way to run python script https://stackoverflow.com/a/67782572/7834019

Comment: @NimaTalebi Hi, I run that piece of code and get empty string in return, anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I update the answer on this link

you should use this to return data from python code:

b = any_object;
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytearray(b,"utf-8"))